# Is "She has as long hair as mine" a correct sentence?

Tags: uncountable-nouns

Is this sentence correct and natural to you?

> She has as long hair as mine.

If this is not correct or natural, why?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the other person has hair the same length as yours you would say "She has hair ***as*** long as mine" because that indicates a comparison of hair on the basis of length. It does not indicate any other similarity, for instance the sentence "She has hair as long as mine but hers is blonde while mine is dark" would be valid as would "She has hair as dark as mine but hers is much shorter" would be a comparison of hair on the basis of colour but with a difference in the length.

The sentence you give is certainly not a standard one and would not indicate a comparison only of the length of the hair, it would carry the suggestion that there were other similarities as well. The more normal way to say it would be "She has long hair like mine" which suggests that her hair is as long as yours, is the same colour and is worn in a similar style.

The "...as 《characteristic》 as..." form is used very widely, for instance "He's as rich as Bill Gates", "Her house is as big as mine" and so on. It even forms part of standard phrases like "He's as poor as a church mouse".

Without the second 'as', however, the meaning changes so that the single 'as' becomes a synonym of 'like'. This form is now very rarely used and has been replaced by 'like' in almost all circumstances.

Comment: I'm so so so sorry. I make a mistake and now I corrected it. I meant "as long as mine".

Comment: Your correction is still not quite normal, in your comment you say "as long as mine" which is perfectly normal but in the corrected question you say "as long hair as mine". This is grammatical, is sometimes used and does mean the same but it is very uncommon and sounds either odd, old fashioned or very formal. I assume it was an error but it's worth knowing that it is correct if you come accross it but don't use it yourself.

Comment: BoldBen, I understand. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

"She has hair as long as mine" is the correct way to say it. The reason is you can put any adjective in the blank in the phrase below

- as ___ as

Examples

- as long as
- as big as

This phrase acts as a qualifier of the noun. When only a single adjective is used it is easier/convenient/customary to say "as ___ as".

Putting noun/s inside this adjective phrase does not make it ungrammatical. However notice the following sentences

- 1. GM has as big bright and red headlights as Toyota.
- 2. GM has headlights as big bright and red as Toyota.
- 3. GM has big headlights as bright and red as Toyota.
- 4. GM has big bright headlights as red as Toyota.
- 5. GM has bright headlights as big and red as Toyota.
- 6. GM has red headlights as big and bright as Toyota.

Sentence number 4  means GM and Toyota both have headlights. GM has big bright headlights, Toyota may or may not have big bright headlights. GM's headlights are as red as Toyota's.

Sentence number 1 and 2 means GM and Toyota both have headlights. GM has headlights that are as big as, as bright as, as red as Toyota's.

I would still use sentence number 2. Why? Because in the first part of the sentence I get to know what is being compared, and in the second part of the sentence I get to know what qualities are being compared.

Answer (score 0):

One difficulty with your sentence is that "hair" is a collective noun; it does not accept the indefinite article "a" without losing its collective quality. For example:
*She has as long a ruler as mine* would be acceptable because the indefinite article acts upon the noun. But if you say She has *a hair* as long as mine it changes the meaning to suggest that one of her hairs is very long, but that the rest of her hair isn't up to that standard.

Comment: I don't see how *hair* being a collective noun makes any difference to the grammaticality of the sentence. So since *she has as big a nose as mine* is grammatical, shouldn't *she has as long legs as mine* and *she has as long hair as mine* also be grammatical?

Comment: Thanks, dclxvispqr. That's the point. A friend of mine told me that I can't use this construction with noncount nouns. But what makes me more confused is the fact that "I have as much money as you" is very common.

Comment: @Kosuke "much" is an exception, it seems, and using "much" in the construct works for pretty much any uncountable nouns ("as much food as she has", even "as much hair"). But other adjectives can't be used that way ("as dark skin as she has" sounds off, for example).

Comment: So can I conclude that "you can't put 'as adjective' in front of non-count nouns, but 'as much' is an exception"?